# Is constraint diagram an useful tool for unmanned aircraft design?

Tags: aircraft-design

I've come across constraint sizing diagram methods for preliminary but its for general aviation aircraft. Are the general equations used for drawing performance curves valid for unmanned aircraft design which weigh 50-150kg?

[image]

Comment: Community, please see [Drone/UAV Question FAQ](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4390/what-is-the-site-policy-on-drone-questions) and decide if you would like to answer this or migrate (Upvote this comment for migrate)

Comment: What would lead you to believe it might not be applicable?

Comment: Allow me to give an opposing opinion, it could be answered here, the physics are the same. Up to 150 kg? Could be a manned aircraft. No need to migrate this one away I would say.

Answer (score 1):

That sizing plot can definitely be used also for UAV. Obviously you have to use the relevant requirements: for example, the blue line translating the takeoff length, most probably derives from some FAR or MIL rules which might not be suitable for UAV.

Comment: Dear downvoter,  could you please explain how this answer can be improved?

Comment: Ok, I'll bite. I downvoted this answer as the tooltip says "It is not useful..." in any meaningful way. It's too short, it lacks any detail and most of all, it does not answer the question. The question was "Are the general equations used for drawing performance curves valid for unmanned aircraft design" which was not addressed. TBH, the question was not a good one, and therefore at that point you're much better off seeking improvement from the question asker than writing a substandard answer to a substandard question.

Comment: We're after quality questions and answers here, answering substandard questions just fuels the fire of substandard questions.

Comment: @Jamiec: ok, thanks for your explanation. In my opinion the question isn't that bad otherwise I (or anyone else) couldn't have answered and it would have been massive downvoted or even closed